# Can I Re-Assign TFS Work Items to Checked-In Code?

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to go back and tie work items to code that's already been checked into TFS? For example . . . A developer picks the wrong work item, or forgets to pick a work item? I can see work item details for ChangeSets, but the work item page is read-only.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you go to the work item and go to the Links tab, you should be able to add/edit a link to a Changeset.  I think that should do the trick.

M.

Comment: This trick also works if you associate a checkin with the wrong item.  You can remove the link to the change-set from the incorrect item and add a link to the change-set for the correct item.

Comment: The only problem I see is that added this way the Work Item won't show in the list of Related Work Items of the change set. I refreshed and reopened the change set several times and still doesn't show. Correction! It appears that there is some sort of latency or you have to close some the windows to empty some cached values. It eventually showed up. All is good!