# TFS: Retroactively tie check in with ticket

Tags: c#

I have been working on something for which a ticket was not yet open. I made multiple checkins but didn't have them associated with a ticket. Now that the ticket has been created I have been trying to find a way to associate my previous checkins with it with no luck. Is this even possible?

Comment: this might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368664/can-i-re-assign-tfs-work-items-to-checked-in-code

Comment: That was it! Thanks... post that as the answer and I'll mark it correct thanks.

Comment: Ahh WTF I can't upvote your comment for some reason. I'll try again later.

Comment: Glad it worked! - added the answer just for completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the work item and go to the Links tab, you can add a link to a Changeset.